# WMI script to monitor SQL Server replication status

Tags: sql-server, database, wmi, database-replication

I am using SQL Server Management Studio, and I have replication that is replicating my current database server to a backup/history database server.

I am wondering if/how I could monitor the status of the replication using WMI. I have no experience really with WMI, but it would help a lot if we could use it to get the status. We are trying to avoid using an SQL job for monitoring the status, but not sure if it is possible via WMI.

I am doing transaction replication on the server, and using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no WMI interface into replication. You might want to look at the replication monitor class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.replication.replicationmonitor.aspx